# mac os: g++ failed to add framework support

Tags: macos, g++

Code:

```
#include <Security/Security.h>

int main() {
}
```

Compile:

```
$ /Developer/usr/bin/g++  test.cpp  -framework Security
test.cpp:1:31: error: Security/Security.h: No such file or directory
```

Or:

```
$ /Developer/usr/bin/g++  test.cpp  -F /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/
test.cpp:1:31: error: Security/Security.h: No such file or directory
```

**System Info**
Mac: 10.6.5
Xcode: 3.2.5
G++: i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one day has passed and no one answered my question, I'd like to share my solution with those who might run into similar problems.

To compile with Framework support:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/g++ test.cpp -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include
```

Or in a more elegant way:

```
/Developer/usr/bin/g++ test.cpp -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```