# Is it possible to make a .framework on OSX with g++

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, g++

I know that it is possible to make *.dylib* files with g++ compiler on the MacOSX platform. I want to make a *.framework* grouping headers and library. Is it possible to use g++ compiler for that? If not is there any command line interface tool for that purpose? (I want to avoid using xCode if possible)

Comment: Might this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894501/mac-os-g-failed-to-add-framework-support ?

Comment: In fact i already know how to compile with some frameworks I want to make one myself and can't seem to find how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wanted to avoid using Xcode, but here is a nice link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html Follow the instructions ONLY for creating the framework, you'll get a .framework file. With the .framework file that you can place anywhere in your computer, you can compile outside of Xcode like so.

if in your current directory:

```
cwd=$(pwd)
g++ -Wall somefiles.c -o run "-I $(pwd)/some/path/name.framework -F $(pwd)/some/path/ -framework name"
```

otherwise

```
g++ -Wall somefiles.c -o run "-I /full/path/name/name.framework -F /full/path/name/ -framework name"
```